# Multiple inheritance from multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base1{
public:
    int x;
};
class base2{
public:
    int x;
};

class derived1: public base1, public base2{
    // Contains...  base1::x, base2::x
};
class derived2: public base1, public base2{
    // Contains...  base1::x, base2::x 
};

class derived: public derived1, public derived2{

};
```

If I am right, the class `derived` will contain four integers.
But I can't access them with 
`derived1::base1::x, derived1::base2::x, derived2::base1::x, derived2::base2::x`

It shows ambiguity error. `('base1' is ambiguous base of 'derived')` 
Am I missing something? How should I resolve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when you use the scope resolution operator to disambiguate between members, you don't name a "path" to the member. You instead name, however indirectly, the base class where the member comes from.

Since the class name is injected into the scope of the class, and as a result, into the scope of any class that derives from it, you are just naming `base1` and `base2` in a verbose manner. I.e. all the following are equivalent for the member access:

```
derived d;
d.base1::x;
d.derived1::base1::x;
d.derived1::derived1::base1::base1::x;
```

That's why the ambiguity occurs. The way to do it, is to **cast** the object into a `derived1&` or `derived2&`, and then use member access via `base1::x` and `base2::x` on that.

```
static_cast<derived1&>(d).base1::x;
```

Comment: Good technique!  The one (and only) time I got to speak with Bjarne, I had asked him how one should do that.  Now I know.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thank you very much.

Comment: what if `x` is declared `protected:` in base1 and base2?

Comment: @SymonSaroar - Access specifiers don't affect how lookup works. They only make the access allowed or disallowed *after* the lookup is done.